# Windows Authentication and memberships and roles provider

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been in the dark about the windows auth. for quite sometime now and was wondering if you brilliant people could help me out.  I need to use windows authentication but still harness the power of the memberships provider.  what i am doing is creating a user with the membership provider based on my windows username.  the problem is i have authentication="forms" (Which this works locally).  What i am trying to do now is when i change it to authenication ="windows" - i cannot get the request.servervariables["LOGON_USER"] name to appear.  it is always blank.  Could someoen please help in regards to this matter.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Integrated Authentication must be enabled in IIS in order for LOGON_USER to be populated.